# Running composer in a different directory than current

Tags: php, composer-php

I don't know if this question has been asked, because searching finds results mostly about moving the libraries installation directory.

I have a globally installed composer command. Is there a way to run, for example, `composer install` in a different directory than current, i.e. to specify the directory in which I would like tu run the command?

E.g. being in `/home/someuser`, I would like to acquire the same result as in running `composer install` it inside `/home/someuser/myproject`. Of course, one way would be to simply change the current directory, run composer and go back.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Try `composer install -h`. There you'll find an option `--working-dir` (or `-d`). And that's what you're looking for.

Then run:

```
composer install --working-dir=/home/someuser/myproject
```

You can find more in [composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global-options).

Depending on your operating system, the `=` might need to be removed:

```
composer install --working-dir /home/someuser/myproject
```

Comment: `-d=/home/someuser/myproject` actually throws an error for me. Current version of composer seems to accept `-d /home/user/myproject/` instead.

Comment: AFAIK it depens on the operating system (Windows, Linux, OS X). Thank you for your comment, I've updated the answer to make the OS differences more clear.

Comment: using `=` made my build fail a million times, thanks for adding this detail :)

Comment: It was not working on linux. You need to create composer.json file with curly brackets: {} in it. And then all was ok.

Comment: works excellent for me

Answer (score 18):

In addition to the above answer from Tomáš Votruba i had to append the = charachter on OSX. So the full command would be:

```
composer install -d=/home/someuser/myproject
```

My first post on SO so was unable to simply add this as a comment.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me, PHP 7.3 on ubuntu 18.04

Install

> composer install --working-dir=/your_composer_dir

Update

> composer update --working-dir=/your_composer_dir

Answer (score 1):

I tried what others said, but it was giving me: `Invalid working directory specified 'PATH' does not exist.` Although it was my working dir that contained `composer.json`!

I don't know why anyway, but this worked for me (only for gnu/linux users):

```
composer --working-dir=$(pwd)
```

And by the way, if you had run composer -h, it would've told you the solution:

> `-d`, `--working-dir=WORKING-DIR`  If specified, use the given directory as working directory.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a Windows machine with PHPStorm (terminal) and this worked for me.

```
composer install --working-dir /home/someuser/myproject
```

My Linux OS machines require me to use

```
composer install --working-dir=/home/someuser/myproject
```

Note: You may be able to substitute ~/ for /home/someuser/ if your path is super long.

Answer (score -6):

Run:

```
cd /home/mysites/google.com
```

Then run:

```
composer require facebook/graph-sdk
```

Above steps will open up the directory named (google.com) and install facebook Graph SDK there.

Comment: I don't think that changing the directory is wanted. Additionally, if the requirement is to run `composer install`, why did you introduce some package to be installed?