# cannot run composer command in project root

Tags: laravel, ssh, composer-php, cpanel

I am trying to run laravel project in cPanel.

The problem is that `composer` runs outside the project root directory but not inside the project having `composer.json`file.

[image: Composer not working in project root]

cPanel returns `Killed` when i try to run `composer` as in the image below:

[image: Killed Issue]

**Edit:**

Looking on the comments i have tried to run `composer --help` but still there is `Killed` issue.

[image: composer --help command]

I have upgraded the memory limit to `1024M` from custom php.ini file as:

[image: Upgraded memory limit from multiphp]

but it is not yet changing in the terminal:

[image: memory limit check from terminal]

**Could it be php configuration issues or some server issues?**

Can anyone shed some light on this issue? I can update the question if it is not clear.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33082705/4171578. That is, maybe trying to run the command in the project root is not worth the effort, and you can run the command where it works, and just specify the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server runs out of memory when `composer` is executed thus the error message : `Killed`.

If you have access to more resources you might try to increase the ram and try again, otherwise you can just `composer install` on your local machine and upload the `vendor` folder *to get you going for now* until you sort the memory issue on your server.

Edit: from the screenshots I noticed that you didn't upload the `composer.lock` file, you might want to try uploading that file and simply run `composer install`  as it's should require much less memory than `composer update` (since the dependencies won't be resolved on your live server but simply installed according to the hashes in your `composer.lock` file).

Comment: updated the post. and other thing is like i am not installing the dependency and just trying to run the `composer` command only.

Comment: not sure what do you mean by running `composer` command only ? it will try to install the dependencies per default, eg. if you run `composer --help` it will work fine and you will see the help message, not sure if increasing the memory from cPanel will affect the memory limit of the php when run in `CLI` mode as usually there is a different setting for that..

Comment: as per your comment i have tried to run `composer --help` but it is still showing `Killed`. I have also added the image for the command.

Comment: the OS is definitely killing the process as soon as it starts, no sure about your configuration but you will need probably to increase the swap/ram to sort this