# How do I update a composer.json file located in a specific directory?

Tags: ubuntu, composer-php

I've recently started managing a system that uses Composer to handle dependencies and I need to update it. When logging into the Ubuntu console I run the `composer update` command, but it throws an error saying it does not find the .json file. I've managed to find it but it's nested in a subdirectory, and I wouldn't know how to word a command that finds it there. I'm very much a newbie in managing this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I've tried running the `composer update` command, but it throws an error saying it does not find the .json file.

Solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080068/running-composer-in-a-different-directory-than-current)

Comment: Please add the error message you ask about to the question by [edit]ing it in.  And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Why not use `cd` to get to that subdirectory? Usually, that is the main folder of your application, so it should not be a secret

Comment: Hi @hakre !  Thank you for letting me know proper procedure for posting, I'm also a newb at this site's etiquette. I have managed to resolve it thanks to a previous comment. Cheers!

Comment: @NicoHaase I did not know of the command in question, but using "composer update --working-dir" did indeed work. I will investigate the command you mentioned anyway. Thanks!

Comment: The quick SO intro: using `cd` would be off-topic, because it is about general computer use (use another Stackexchange site to ask what you can do next after SSH into a computer). To ask about `composer -d` looks on-topic as per the reference. And that's already it. And thanks for your feedback.